# How to stop the join plugin post-build project if any of the downstream job fails in Jenkins

Tags: build, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have one start job A which uses conditional build step to run a few downstream jobs (B1, B2, B3, ...). I also use join plugin to join those jobs and then start another job C as a join post-build project to build. The reason I use post-build option is I need to pass parameters through all these jobs. However if one of the downstream jobs (B1 or B2 or ...) fails, the job C still runs though I never check "trigger even if some of downstream projects are unstable". Anyone knows the reason? And how to solve the problem? Thanks for shedding some lights on it.

Answer (score 0):

After a few tests I found that join plugin seems not working well with conditional build step plugin, so I removed join plugin and instead checked "block until the triggered projects finish builds" option for each conditional step, then put the join project at the end as a normal triggered job. It works.